# Tunnel Performance Parameters

Tags: performance, http, kubernetes, tcp, tunnel

I'm currently running [Chisel](https://github.com/jpillora/chisel) on my EKS cluster as a pod, and I would like to perform a stress test & create observability for it.

What I'm not sure of are the parameters to look for on that test.

In other words, how can I know if my tunnel is well-functioned and I can add more clients to it, or it's already on its limit and I need to take actions accordingly.

I'm already testing if I have a connection on my tunnel, but I'm yet to determine the quality of it.

Comment: How exactly do you set up the stress test? Please also give more details on your Kubernetes env - is it bare-metal/on cloud?

Comment: I didn't set up the stress test yet, I want to know what to look for in that test, like parameters that will indicate if my tunnel is functioning well or not.

The env is deployed on AWS public cloud provider, on an EKS cluster.

Thank you for your reply